# Can I safely remove Inno Setup script sections from third party tools like [_ISTool]?

Tags: inno-setup

I have in my scripts:

```
[_ISTool]
EnableISX=true
```

Do I need to keep these any more?

I know that it is part of the legacy ISTools extensions which are now part of Inno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup does not use that section at all. It uses only the sections listed in the [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/).

So unless you use some 3rd party extension or tool that makes use of that, you can safely remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed this section and it compiles with no errors.